# Detect Mock Location is enabled or disabled in Flutter

Tags: flutter

My question is that I am using flutter platform to develop an app for my client and I want that my developed app should be able to be detect mock location status from android phone settings so I can check whether the location is coming from gps provider or mock location app. And if mock location is enabled then my app should throw an error msg

Answer (score 6):

i had the same problem and i fixed it by coding in java and implement in flutter project.
here is what i did:
1) add this to your Main_Activity in flutter project.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;

import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.io/location";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
                new MethodCallHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {

                        if (call.method.equals("getLocation")) {
                            boolean b = getMockLocation();
                            result.success(b);
                        } else {
                            result.notImplemented();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    public static boolean isMockSettingsON(Context context) {
        // returns true if mock location enabled, false if not enabled.
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
            if (Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0"))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public static boolean areThereMockPermissionApps(Context context) {
        int count = 0;

        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages =
                pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
            try {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName,
                        PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

                // Get Permissions
                String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

                if (requestedPermissions != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                        if (requestedPermissions[i]
                                .equals("android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION")
                                && !applicationInfo.packageName.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("Got exception " , e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (count > 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }


    private boolean getMockLocation() {
        boolean b ;
        b= areThereMockPermissionApps(MainActivity.this);
        return b;
    }
}
```

2) use it in your flutter_dart Code like this:

```
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.io/location');



bool mocklocation = false;
  Future<void> _getMockLocation() async {
    bool b;
    try {
      final bool result = await platform.invokeMethod('getLocation');
      b = result;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      b = false;
    }

    mocklocation = b;
  }


if (mocklocation == true) {

       return showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return WillPopScope(
                onWillPop: (){},
                              child: AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Location'),
                  content: Text('Your Location is fake'),
                ),
              );
            });
    }
```

3) for more information and example: 
 https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Answer (score 3):

Barzan's answer is very good, there's also a Flutter package named trust_location, you can find it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/trust_location).

You can use it as following to check mock location:

```
bool isMockLocation = await TrustLocation.isMockLocation;
```

So, I recommend to use it.

Comment: Only work on Android not IOS

Comment: i think in iOS you can't fake your location @AbedPutra cmiiw